# How to dispatch an action from a component attached on the same store section

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Sorry if the question looks stupid, I'm approaching at redux/redux.

I'm not able to understand if I'm doing something wrong :(

If I have a component that is attached, let's say, to the store section called "user'

```js
Class UserComponent extends React.Component {
  [...]
}
const UserWithStore = connect(mapStateToProps)(TokenComponent);
```

where map state to props is :

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        user: state['user']
    }
};
```

Whenever from the user component I trigger an action that updates the store section like:

this.props.dispatch(action)

Basically, the component goes in a loop because obviously, I'm updating the same portion of the store.

Is it anti-pattern? I have to check always previous props vs current props or I should trigger actions from a different component?

Thank you for helping me

Comment: If I am understanding what you're saying, you have a component that is subscribed to a portion of the state (user in this case). That same component can also trigger an event that updates that portion of the state (e.g. an action that changes the user field in the state). This means that the component now has received new props and needs to re render. If that's your concern, that is perfectly normal, actually that is the wanted behavior.

Comment: thank you so much! basically I have to compare the props in order to avoid useless component loops